# How currently use interface in EJB?

Tags: java, ejb

I want to use interface in me EJB, but I get this exception:

`Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEJB0406: No EJB found with interface of type 'beans.database.DatabaseUserManager' for binding beans.security.RegistrationBean/databaseUserManager"}`

Thats example of my interface:

```
public interface FieldChecker {
//doing something
}
```

And how I use it:

```
@Singleton
public class DatabaseUserManager implements FieldChecker {
//doing something
}
```

I have a feeling that I should use some kind of annotation, can someone help me?

Comment: Word of advice: don't cut things out of the error message, post it exactly as you get it. You are not in a position to dictate what is and is not relevant to the reader. Better have too much than not enough.

Comment: @Gimby, okay, I fix it, thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You have to add @Local to the interface to indicate that this is the local interface (there could be a remote interface for EJB remoting)

```
@Local
public interface FieldChecker {
//doing something
}
```

Comment: I try this, but problem remains

Comment: What's the package of @Singleton that you used?

Comment: I use package 'beans.security' for @Singleton and 'beans.security.tools' for interface, should they be in the same package?

Comment: No I mean from which package do you import Singleton?

Comment: from beans.database

Comment: from javax.ejb.Singleton